# Checking that a mocked function is called in Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am working on an API in Typescript using Node and Express.

I have the following mock implementation for an API key manager class in Jest:

```
import {ApiKeyManager} from '../../api_key_manager_client/api_key_manager';

jest.mock('../../api_key_manager_client/api_key_manager', () => {
  return {
    ApiKeyManager: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        secretId: 'WEBHOOKS_API_KEY',
        getApiKey: () => 'xxx',
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

and I'm testing as follows:

```
it('should run the callback endpoint class when the given API key matches', async () => {
    const payload = {...};
    const res = await request(app)
        .post('/callback')
        .set({'X-API-KEY': 'xxx', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        .send(payload);
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(201);
    expect(ApiKeyManager).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

This works and I can test successfully that the ApiKeyManager class is called.

However, I'd like to check that the public `getApiKey` method in that class is called specifically, but I'm not sure how to test that the mock received that particular method call?  It should happen once so I'd like to test that.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: As written `ApiKeyManager` returns an object whose `getApiKey` method is _not_ a mock function, so you can't.

Comment: How would it work if `getApiKey` was a mock function? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Can you show the assertion code and the error details?

Comment: is `ApiKeyManager` a class or it is a function?

Comment: It's a class that I wrote.